# Getting MAX and MIN values for all values in a field

Tags: sql

I am trying to get `MIN` and `MAX` values of one field for all rows.

`MIN (WEEK_P)` should be always one value `20220917` for all fields all the time. Now the Window Function doesn't work for some reason. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT
    FNL_DC AS 'DC',
    FNL_MC AS 'BUDGET_CHAIN',
    FNL_MODE AS 'MODE',
    FNL_WEEK,
    MIN( WEEK_P ) OVER ( PARTITION BY WEEK_P ORDER BY WEEK_P ) AS MIN_WEEK_P, /* trying to get MIN value of all the values (ex. 20220917) -- right now I have 20220924, 20221001, 20220917,NULL */
    MAX( DEWEDT ) OVER ( PARTITION BY DEWEDT ORDER BY DEWEDT ) AS MAX_DEWEDT  /* trying to get MAX value for all the values (ex. 20221008) -- right now I have 20221008, 20220917, NULL */
FROM
    table
```

Let me know.

Comment: would you try without `OVER()` clause ?

Comment: what do you mean? If I just type MIN(WEEK_P) I do get different values, and I need the same value for all the rows.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: … See the [help] for more on [how to ask good questions](/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topic. See also the [tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055).

Comment: Generally, SQL questions should be tagged with the RDBMS being used, and the question should specify the RDBMS and version.

Comment: there is an issue with your partition by clause. Can you please show the actual rows or sample data ? I believe you need to define the granularity for the level of partitioning

Answer (score 0):

MIN(WEEK_P) OVER (PARTITION BY WEEK_P ORDER BY WEEK_P) -- I see an issue here. The partition by clause will cause the window function to act on a set of rows that has the same value. Here you are partitioning it by WEEK_P and for each unique value of WEEK_P your window function will try to get the MIN(WEEK_P) which is the same.

I would like to know at what granularity you want the MIN function to work.